# Jquery code working in all browsers apart from FF

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have written the following jquery sitting in the head tags of my HTML

It is supposed to bring the image that is being hovered over to full opacity and slide another image over it from the right, then return when un-hovered.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  $('ul#img-nav li').css({
   "opacity": .5
  });

  $('ul#img-nav li').hover(function() {
   $(this).stop(true).animate({"opacity":1});
   $(this).children('.overlay').stop(true).animate({"left" : "18px" });


  }, function() {
   $(this).stop(true).animate({"opacity":.5});
   $(this).children('.overlay').stop(true).animate({"left" : "180px" });

  });
 });

</script>
```

This works fine in Safari, Chrome, IE (7,8) but not in FF 3.6.

Any suggestions why this might be?

Sorry I forgot to say that the opacity works but the sliding image doesn't.

Many thanks

UPDATE: new to stackoverflow so I hope i'm putting this requested code in the correct place

HTML:

```
<ul id="img-nav">
            <a href="index.html">
                <li>
                    <img src="images/nav-img1.jpg" alt="nav-img1" width="146" height="145" />
                    <img class="overlay" src="images/overlay-exterior.png" alt="overlay-exterior" width="123" height="135" />
                </li>
            </a>
            <a href="exterior.html">
                <li>
                    <img src="images/nav-img2.jpg" alt="nav-img2" width="146" height="145" />
                    <img class="overlay" src="images/overlay-exterior.png" alt="overlay-exterior" width="123" height="134" />
                </li>
            <a href="maintenance.html">
                <li>
                    <img src="images/nav-img3.jpg" alt="nav-img3" width="146" height="145" />
                    <img class="overlay" src="images/overlay-exterior.png" alt="overlay-exterior" width="123" height="134" />
                </li>
            <a href="other.html">
                <li class="last">
                    <img src="images/nav-img4.jpg" alt="nav-img4" width="146" height="145" />
                    <img class="overlay" src="images/overlay-exterior.png" alt="overlay-exterior" width="123" height="134" />
                </li>
            </a>        

    </ul><!--END #img-nav-->
```

CSS

```
ul#img-nav li   {float:left; width: 146px; margin-right:103px; position: relative; display:block; height: 145px; overflow:hidden;} 

ul#img-nav li img   {position:absolute; top:0; left:0;}

ul#img-nav li img.overlay   {position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 180px; }
```

I also want them to be clickable links.

Also, I have noticed the slider works in IE8 but not the opacity change.

NB. It works in IE6 too

Thanks again

UPDATE:

When testing using FF on a separate windows machine running XP (my main machine is Mac OSX 10.5) it still doesn't slide across, just the opacity changes (which is the original problem).

Comment: Works in IE but not FF? Whaaaaat...??

Comment: Try disabling all plugins in FF, and force a refresh on the page (just to make sure it's nothing getting in the way)

Comment: Disabled everything apart from Firebug but still no go and been shift-refreshing. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ok, seems your HTML is not valid. `a` tags should not wrap `li` ones, see HTML below. With that change the JS also needed to change.

As a side note, instead of the chained `children().children(..)` calls a single `find(..)` call will also work.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $('ul#img-nav li').css({
            "opacity": .5
        });

        $('ul#img-nav li').hover(function() {
            $(this).stop(true).animate({"opacity":1});
            $(this).children().children('.overlay').stop(true).animate({"left" : "18px" });
        }, function() {
            $(this).stop(true).animate({"opacity":.5});
            $(this).children().children('.overlay').stop(true).animate({"left" : "180px" });
        });

    });
</script>
<style type="text/css"> 
    ul#img-nav li   {float:left; width: 146px; margin-right:103px; position: relative; display:block; height: 145px; overflow:hidden;} 
    ul#img-nav li img   {position:absolute; top:0; left:0;}
    ul#img-nav li img.overlay   {position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 180px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="img-nav">
    <li>
        <a href="index.html">
            <img src="base.jpg" alt="nav-img1" width="146" height="145" />
            <img class="overlay" src="overlay.png" alt="overlay-exterior" width="123" height="135" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="exterior.html">
            <img src="base.jpg" alt="nav-img2" width="146" height="145" />
            <img class="overlay" src="overlay.png" alt="overlay-exterior" width="123" height="134" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="maintenance.html">
            <img src="base.jpg" alt="nav-img3" width="146" height="145" />
            <img class="overlay" src="overlay.png" alt="overlay-exterior" width="123" height="134" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="last">
        <a href="other.html">
            <img src="base.jpg" alt="nav-img4" width="146" height="145" />
            <img class="overlay" src="overlay.png" alt="overlay-exterior" width="123" height="134" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine on FF for me. Perhaps you cannot load the icon, making it appear as if nothing is happening on Firefox?

http://jsfiddle.net/NGyxN/2/

Comment: the .png i'm trying to slide across loads fine when I browse for it in Firebug. Is that what you mean? Cheers